# Monarch/Groundwork won't update the hosts.cfg in Nagios

Tags: monitoring, monitor, nagios

Given that Monarch/Groundwork is made to provide a GUI interface to Nagios, this should be a simple question, but I'm a little stuck.

How can I add a host to nagios in Groundwork?  According to my GW tab, my new host is configured.  If I look at the nagios hosts tab, I see that it's not present.

If I look in /usr/local/groundwork/nagios/etc/hosts.cfg, I see that the file clearly hasn't been updated.  Based off the text at the top of the file, this would normally be updated by monarch.cgi.

If I add the host to the hosts.cfg file, then restart nagios, it correctly appears, but now I have to config the entire host manually, which is the entire reason to have GW or Monarch.

So, the question is, how do I get monarch to update my nagios config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first check permissions, can you show the output of these?
ls -lla hosts.cfg
groups

You could just try adding the GW user to whatever group the hosts.cfg file belongs to:
useradd -G

And make sure the file is group-editable: chmod g+rw hosts.cfg

Comment: Permissions shouldn't be an issue, unless I'm missing something obvious.  We've setup a nagios user to run groundwork, and it owns all the nagios config files, as well as the GW files.


# ls -lla hosts.cfg hostgroups.cfg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 2288 May 20 13:10 hostgroups.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 5898 May 10 16:17 hosts.cfg

By this point, I've become fairly accustomed to going into the nagios/etc config settings and restarting GW.  But I'd much rather have GW working as intended.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting on the comment.  Looks like the comment section doesn't format as easily.

    `# ls -lla hosts.cfg hostgroups.cfg 
    -rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 2288 May 20 13:10 hostgroups.cfg
    -rw-r--r-- 1 nagios nagios 5898 May 10 16:17 hosts.cfg`

Comment: I see. I'm guessing you already followed all the steps in this video:  http://www.gwos.com/2011/nagios-migration/  ?

Comment: Actually, I hadn't seen that video.  I'm taking over this monitoring environment from a team that's no longer available, so I'm not sure how they previously maintained it. 

Since I've got Nagios working fairly well now from simply editing the text files, I'll doublecheck the paths in nagios.cfg and try importing it into GW to see how that works.

Comment: That worked.  After importing all the changes I had made to nagios/etc files, it correctly updated the GW config.  

The major key was including the 'commit' step.  I didn't realize that after **every** change, committing the config change was necessary.  Lesson learned.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it sorted out!